# Create clean simple HTML/CSS using best practice examples

Tags: html, css, editor

I am having a hard time creating clean maintainable HTML/CSS code. Is there an editor, book or webpage that can help me using best practices.

This is some examples:

1. Naming of divs and classes: You might have an area with a user profile. How would you name the id and classes? (#author_profile, .username, .userBirthday etc.)
2. Tags or divs: A lot of times I am getting confused on when to create my own divs or use a tag with id/class. Any good examples?
3. Positioning: 99% of the times I set a fixed width on the elements and use float: left/right. Any tips on making CSS positioning more accessible. I have tried a lot of CSS frameworks, but this has not worked for me. Always ends up with deeply nested divs and a lot of classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-builds/from-psd-to-html-building-a-set-of-website-designs-step-by-step/

Start at Nettuts...where i learnt everything i know (pretty much)

Answer (score 4):

Here you go [Web Page Development: Best Practices](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/bestwebdev.html).

Comment: If your going to learn web design, you might aswell learn it from the best in the business

Answer (score -1):

You may as well use this chrome plugin called [CSS Brush](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-brush/mamnhhinmmdpcipjnhflillmhnogoobj?hl=en-US) to check it live on the webpage. The context-sensitive-menu helps you see what all properties exist for a particular style and apply to the element live. After you have done with all the CSS, you may copy them all and paste in your CSS file.